# Offering bounty when there is 1 closure vote

Tags: discussion

I would like to offer a bounty on [this question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/6279/604). Recognizing that there is currently 1 closure vote, I consulted with moderator Danu and he recommended to pose this at meta. Would it be appropriate to offer a bounty now seeing that the closure vote does not seem to be going anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

You've already posted the bounty, but I think it's still worth answering the question in abstract form.

It does not make much sense to disallow bounties on questions with close votes. If this were a real problem it would be prohibited by the software. Additionally setting bounties requires only 75 reputation here while viewing close votes requires 250 reputation for your own posts and 500 for those of others. So in general a user placing a bounty does not even necessarily know whether or not there are close votes.

In this case you could see the single close vote, but I think it's still fine to place a bounty. If there were 3 or 4 votes and the question had a more negative reception a bit more caution would be merited. But even in that case, moderators can remove the bounty (returning the reputation to you) if it appears that the bounty was primarily used to block close-votes rather than out of legitimate interest. Using bounties to deliberately block close votes is usually one of our most minor concerns because it's both rare and ineffective. Except in egregious cases I don't think it's worth worrying about very much.